# "No such table" error when adding users to database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a website using Flask (and Flask-SQLAlchemy for making new users), but when I commit to add a new user to database I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

models.py:

```py
from .__init__ import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Reservation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(128))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))

class user(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    reservations = db.relationship("Reservation")
```

**init**.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"
    print("Initializing app")
    db.init_app(app)
    print("App initialized")

    print("Importing blueprints...")
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")
    print("Registered Blueprints")
    print("Importing database")
    from .models import user, Reservation

    print("Creating database")
    create_database(app)
    db.create_all(app=app)

    return(app)

def create_database(app):
    print("Checking if DB exists")
    if not path.exists("website/" + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print("DB did not exist, has been created right now.")
    else: 
        print("DB exists, nothing has been done.")
```

Code giving me an error:

```py
print("Adding user to database")
new_user = user(userName=username, password=gph(password,method="sha256"))
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

Error log:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
[SQL: INSERT INTO user ("userName", password) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('bingusCoder', 'sha256$vYx5OSQyP182M8Jw$85e0690712b68b4b11e181904b44387eba2c1e1cdacebfbb4a60426c4ecdee81')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

[image: More info on errors]

Comment: It looks like your SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is DB_NAME but in `create_database` it's website/DB_NAME.  You can probably do `db.create_all()` regardless as `create_all` will just ignore existing tables.

Comment: I tried removing the website/ in create_database but it still gave me an OperationalError. Anything else that you can notice that is wrong?

Comment: There are only two possibilities: the tables haven't been created, or the code is using the wrong database.   I would remove the `path.exists` check to ensure that the tables will always be created; I'd also set `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` to `True` in the app config to see that the DDL statements are being emitted.

Comment: I set SQLALCHEMY_ECHO to true and when I start up the program it gives me these 2 lines:
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT

And right before the traceback, I get this: "POST /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: And I also get this when my code tries to add the new user to non-existing tables that should exist because I did create_all():
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO user ("userName", password) VALUES (?, ?)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00103s] ('bingusCoder', 'sha256$Xp7N6LLsYDg8yImc$04c9e2e19e6e264c1f39387a82b226e3e86961ef082e1aa0d3c42166bcc768bd')
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK

Comment: Did you remove the `path.exists` check?

Comment: I removed the path.exists check and now when I run my create_database function I get this:

Creating tables
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
Tables created 
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce the problem with your code, but it works in my side. In this case, I will just send my working copy of your code so that you can reference from it.

```py
from os import path

from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from flask import Flask
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"
    print("Initializing app")

    db.init_app(app)
    return app

def create_database(app):
    print("Checking if DB exists")
    if not path.exists(DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print("DB did not exist, has been created right now.")
    else: 
        print("DB exists, nothing has been done.")

class Reservation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(128))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))

class user(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    reservations = db.relationship("Reservation")
app = create_app()
create_database(app)
db.create_all(app=app)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    username, password = "username21", "password"
    new_user = user(userName=username, password=password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

Comment: I think the problem on my side is that I'm separating my code between many files, and there must be something going on in between all of the imports.